# How to perform on-demand mass cache invalidation in Next.js application?

Tags: next.js

On-demand mass cache invalidation

This is more of an investigative question rather than trying to find a solution to a problem.
On our NextJs application, we have managed to incorporate the on-demand revalidation functionality but since our application is fairly complex there seems to always come to the table if there is a method to “invalidate” the entire cache and basically wait for the users to visit the pages in order to generate them once again.

Has anyone else come across such a requirement because there seem to be no posts related on the internet about something like this and the only way is by targeting the specified URLs through webhooks and the revalidation API.